# How do I set up shortcuts for buttons created with code?

Tags: objective-c, macos

How do I set up shortcuts for buttons created with code?
When the user presses a button on the keyboard, it is equivalent to clicking the button with the mouse.
I have never tried it, so I don't know.

---

**Result**

I found the simpler!!

[image]

**End**

Comment: If your question is about macOS, you should include the [tag:macos] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Button Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Tasks/SettingButtonKeyEquiv.html):

> ### Setting a Button’s Key Equivalent
>
> A button can have a key equivalent, so that when the user presses that key, the button responds as though it’s been clicked.
>
> Note that if you set the key equivalent to Return, that button becomes the default button.
>
> You typically set a button’s key equivalent in Interface Builder. To do so, select the button and open the attributes pane of the inspector. Disclose the attributes for the button, click in the Key Equiv. field, and type the key or key combination you want to associate with the button. (You remove the key equivalent by pressing Clear.)
>
> To set the key equivalent programmatically, use `setKeyEquivalent:` with the character. For example, to set it to Return, use:
>
> ```
> [myButton setKeyEquivalent:@"\r"];
> ```
>
> To set the button’s key equivalent to non-print character, you can use the key constants defined by `NSResponder`, as in the following example, which sets a button’s key equivalent to the left arrow key.
>
> ```
> unichar arrowKey = NSLeftArrowFunctionKey;
> [button setKeyEquivalent:[NSString stringWithCharacters:&arrowKey length:1]];
> ```

---

In Swift, you set the `keyEquivalent` property:

```
button.keyEquivalent = "\r"
```

Answer (score -1):

UITextField has Text input traits, which has predefined keys.

[image]

or you can do it like

```
textField.returnKeyType = .done
```

Then you can confirm your view controller with UITextFieldDelegate.

```
textField.delegate = self
```

And implement UITextFieldDelegate method

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

     // implement your logic here...

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Comment: The question says “clicking the button with the mouse”. Since iOS devices don't have a mouse, this question is probably about macOS.

Comment: Then it should be tagged with macOS.